# VSCode make Ctrl+click "file, line" in terminal function like Ctrl+click "file:line"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a linter that I run in vscode's terminal. It shows errors in this form:

```
file, line
```

When I ctrl+click on the file, vscode will go to the beginning of the file because it doesn't consider the line number. By default, vscode will go the line number only if there is a colon and no space between the file and the line. Is there a setting or extension to make vscode detect file and line written in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect your linters output to a script which fixes the formatting

```
# linter yourfile > yourreformattingscript
```

Just passthrough the lines you are not interested in and reformat the ones containing "filename, line"